# uname -a gives a wrong kernel version

Tags: kernel, 14.10

I have the 3.16 Linux kernel package installed on my Ubuntu 14.10 server, but when i try to run `uname -a` it gives me this:

```
Linux example.com 3.13.0-36-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 3 21:30:07 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Although that i don't have any of the 3.13 kernel packages installed on my system, and I also don't have any kernel images in /boot for the 3.13 version.

Is there any solution for this? I've seen many [similar questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/547834/uname-r-returns-the-wrong-kernel-version) by the way and non helped.

Comment: Is this server a VPS?  If so, does the host use OpenVZ as the method of virtualization? (We need more information on the type of server, how it was installed/setup, etc.)

Comment: @ThomasW. Yes it's, the host is DigitalOcean and they use KVM. The system on the VPS was Ubuntu 14.04 with the 3.13 kernel but then, i upgraded to 14.10 and removed the old kernel and installed the 3.16.

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: @ThomasW. Ofcourse i did, i am not that noob :3

Comment: Are you absolutely certain they have a KVM setup which allows a kernel independent from the host kernel?

Comment: @ThomasW. Yes, that what they said [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/help/technical/general/) . But i one time, i changed the kernel from their control panel instead of changing it from the server itself, but later i re-changed it to 3.16 but it still the same.. Maybe this has something with it?

Answer (score 0):

Still on the questioning side...  I upgraded to 3.13.0-48-generic on several of my machines, but have one that uname -r reports 3.13.0.46.  When I reviewed it with Synaptic, it shows '48' but the terminal still shows '46.'  I am comfortable that 48 is running, but my trust in terminal has been dented.  GB