# How to figure out currently used kernel if uname does not tell the detailed version?

Tags: boot, kernel

There seems to be a lot of kernels installed:

```
root@v59530:/boot# dpkg -l | grep "linux-[a-z]*-"
ii  linux-aws-headers-4.15.0-1007                 4.15.0-1007.7                           all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0
...
ii  linux-aws-headers-4.15.0-1032                 4.15.0-1032.34                          all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0
ii  linux-aws-headers-4.15.0-1033                 4.15.0-1033.35                          all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0
ii  linux-azure-headers-4.15.0-1009               4.15.0-1009.9                           all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0
...
ii  linux-azure-headers-4.15.0-1032               4.15.0-1032.33                          all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0
ii  linux-gcp-headers-4.15.0-1006                 4.15.0-1006.6                           amd64        Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0
...
ii  linux-gcp-headers-4.15.0-1032                 4.15.0-1032.34                          amd64        Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0
ii  linux-gcp-headers-4.15.0-1033                 4.15.0-1033.35                          amd64        Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0
ii  linux-gke-4.15-headers-4.15.0-1030            4.15.0-1030.32                          amd64        Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0
ii  linux-gke-4.15-headers-4.15.0-1032            4.15.0-1032.34                          amd64        Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0
ii  linux-gke-4.15-headers-4.15.0-1033            4.15.0-1033.35                          amd64        Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-1004-oem                 4.15.0-1004.5                           amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-1005-dell300x            4.15.0-1005.8                           amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-1006-dell300x            4.15.0-1006.10                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
...
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-1030-kvm                 4.15.0-1030.30                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-1030-oem                 4.15.0-1030.35                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-1030-oracle              4.15.0-1030.33                          amd64        Oracle Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-1031-aws                 4.15.0-1031.33                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-1031-azure               4.15.0-1031.32                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-1031-kvm                 4.15.0-1031.31                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-1031-oracle              4.15.0-1031.34                          amd64        Oracle Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-1032-aws                 4.15.0-1032.34                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-1032-azure               4.15.0-1032.33                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-1032-gcp                 4.15.0-1032.34                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-1032-gke                 4.15.0-1032.34                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-1032-kvm                 4.15.0-1032.32                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-1033-aws                 4.15.0-1033.35                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-1033-gcp                 4.15.0-1033.35                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-1033-gke                 4.15.0-1033.35                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-1033-oem                 4.15.0-1033.38                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-kvm-headers-4.15.0-1008                 4.15.0-1008.8                           all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0
...
ii  linux-kvm-headers-4.15.0-1031                 4.15.0-1031.31                          all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0
ii  linux-kvm-headers-4.15.0-1032                 4.15.0-1032.32                          all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                          4.15.0-135.139                          amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development
ii  linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1004                 4.15.0-1004.5                           all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0
...
ii  linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1033                 4.15.0-1033.38                          all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0
ii  linux-oracle-headers-4.15.0-1007              4.15.0-1007.9                           all          Header files related to Oracle Linux kernel version 4.15.0
ii  linux-oracle-headers-4.15.0-1008              4.15.0-1008.10                          all          Header files related to Oracle Linux kernel version 4.15.0
...
ii  linux-oracle-headers-4.15.0-1033              4.15.0-1033.36                          all          Header files related to Oracle Linux kernel version 4.15.0
```

I could not get informed about the current used one:

[picture: trying to get kernel info using uname](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctTEp.png)

```
root@v59530:/boot# uname -r
4.15.0
root@v59530:/boot# uname -v # ???
#1 SMP Thu Apr 22 16:18:59 MSK 2021
root@v59530:/boot# uname -m
x86_64
root@v59530:/boot# uname -a
Linux v59530.1blu.de 4.15.0 #1 SMP Thu Apr 22 16:18:59 MSK 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@v59530:/boot# cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.15.0 (mockbuild@builder7.eng.sw.ru) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Apr 22 16:18:59 MSK 2021
root@v59530:/boot# hostnamectl | grep Kernel
            Kernel: Linux 4.15.0
root@v59530:/boot# cd /etc/default/grub
-bash: cd: /etc/default/grub: No such file or directory
root@v59530:/boot# uname -mrs
Linux 4.15.0 x86_64
root@v59530:/boot# cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"
root@v59530:/boot# cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS \n \l
```

Links that I used during my research:

- [How to I prevent Ubuntu from kernel version upgrade and notification?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938494/how-to-i-prevent-ubuntu-from-kernel-version-upgrade-and-notification)
- [Ubuntu won't boot - kernel error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/955020/ubuntu-wont-boot-kernel-error/955130#955130)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199214/debian-how-to-get-the-current-loaded-kernel-package-name
- https://stackabuse.com/substrings-in-bash
- https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-print-linux-unix-kernel-version/
- [uname -r returns the wrong kernel version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/547834/uname-r-returns-the-wrong-kernel-version)

Expected behavior according to cyberciti.biz:

```
    So my Linux kernel version is 4.15.0-39, where:
    
    4 : Kernel version     
   15 : Major revision 
    0 : Minor revision     
   39 : Patch level or number    
 generic : Linux distro/kernel specific additional info
```

Comment: The current kernel is pointed to by the symbolic link `/boot/vmlinuz` (yes "`z`" - it's a compressed file). So: `ls -l /boot/vmlinuz; ls -lL /boot/ vmlinuz`.

Comment: None of those packages "`linux-*-headers*`" is a "kernel". Look at `dpkg -L` on any of the package names.

Comment: @waltinator My boot folder seems to be empty: `root@v59530:/boot# ls -l`
 returns `total 0`